# Conditional in the Middle of an Expression

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm curious if something like this is possible:

```
print "lajsdflk"+ (if x>1:"123123";else:"0000000") +"!@#"
```

Not specifically printing but just any function with numbers; another example:

```
print 596* (if statementX: 6545; else: 9874) /63
```

If possible I'd like to keep it to one line.

Comment: I added the excel tag, because it seems your question is more about excel than it is about Python.

Comment: The syntax is like this: `print 596* (6545 if True else 9874) /63`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions), like this

```
>>> "lajsdflk" + ("123123" if 5 > 1 else "0000000") + "!@#"
'lajsdflk123123!@#'
>>> "lajsdflk" + ("123123" if 0 > 1 else "0000000") + "!@#"
'lajsdflk0000000!@#'
```

Since Python accepts any Truthy value in the `if`'s expression, you can even use any function, like this

```
>>> "lajsdflk" + ("123123" if "abcd1234".isalnum() else "0000000") + "!@#"
'lajsdflk123123!@#'
```

---

There is another trick people use. It goes like this

```
>>> "lajsdflk" + ("0000000", "123123")[5 > 1] + "!@#"
'lajsdflk123123!@#'
>>> "lajsdflk" + ("0000000", "123123")[0 > 1] + "!@#"
'lajsdflk0000000!@#'
```

Here, a tuple is prepared with the possible outcomes and based on the result of the comparison operation, the possible value is chosen. Here, `5 > 1` is evaluated and found out to be Truthy and since Python's `True` equals 1 and `False` equals `0`, `5 > 1` evaluates to be 1.

```
>>> 0 == False
True
>>> 1 == True
True
```

**Note:** This trick has a problem. Consider this case,

```
>>> 1 + (2, 3/0)[4 > 0] + 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Because, when the tuple is created all the values are evaluated and Python cannot divide `1` by `0`. But, this problem will not be there with conditional expression,

```
>>> 1 + (2 if 4 > 0 else 3/0) + 5
8
```

Because it evaluates the values only if the branch is hit.